# Overload subscription on observable

Tags: knockout.js, subscription, observable

Is it possible to overload a pre-existing subscription on an observable and if so how?

```
this.myObservable = ko.observable();
this.myObservable.subscribe(function(value){
    /* stuff worth subscribing for */
});
/* stuff going on */
/* ... */
/* more stuff going on */

// now at this point I want to check if something has subscribed to
// this.myObservable and if so I want the subscription to do a bit extra
```

I understand that I could place the "bit extra" in the initial subscription in the first place, but I want to know if it's possible to check for the subscription and then overload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout doesn't provide any way to extend a subscription. But you could wrap the `subscribe` method to provide a way to do so. Here's an example:

```
ko.subscribable.fn.subscribe = (function (originalFunction) {
    return function (callback, callbackTarget, event) {
        var boundCallback = callbackTarget ? callback.bind(callbackTarget) : callback,
            currentCallback = boundCallback,
            passthroughCallback = function (value) { currentCallback(value) },
            subscription = originalFunction.call(this, passthroughCallback, null, event);

        subscription.extend = function (newCallback) {
            currentCallback = newCallback.bind(null, currentCallback);
        };
        return subscription;
    }
})(ko.subscribable.fn.subscribe);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/LKrr9/

You also mention being able to retrieve a subscription from an observable later on. You might accomplish that by adding a line in the function above like this:

```
this.latestSubscription = subscription;
```

This assumes that subscriptions won't be disposed. If you want to get the latest non-disposed subscription, it'll be a bit more complicated.

NOTE: The above method of extending `subscribe` only works in Knockout >=3.1.0. For prior versions, you've have to attach the new `subscribe` method in an extender.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure there is a magical JavaScript way of doing it but one way that just came to mind for some reason when reading this (not that fancy, mind you) is like this -

```
function doSomething() { alert('Hey'); }
function doSomethingElse() { alert('Hey2'); }

ko.extenders.functionAdder = function (target, firstFunc) {
    target.functionBag = target.functionBag ? target.functionBag : [];
    target.functionBag.push(firstFunc);
    target.subscribe(function(value){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(target.functionBag, function (item) {
            item();
        }); 
    });
}    
self.things = ko.observableArray([new Message('Hey')]).extend({ functionAdder: doSomething });

// Later on

target.functionBag.push(doSomethingElse);
```

**Example -**

http://jsfiddle.net/k94qT/

There may be a more appropriate way to reopen the function and add things to it but that sounds like Ember.js's reopenClass and I don't know of anything like that in Knockout.js

Comment: Either it answers the question directly or not, I like this. +1

Comment: Just curious... what's the difference between this solution and simply subscribing twice?

Comment: There is only one subscription that needs to be disposed, you could add and remove actions on demand, and it is down right cooler.